# mongodb java driver not finding master after rs.stepDown()

Tags: mongodb, grails

Grails 2.2.1
MongoDB GORM plugin 1.2

When running with a replica set I am finding that stepping down the primary causes the following infinitely repeated errors in the java driver.

```
2013-09-09 16:00:19,655 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] ERROR grails.app.services.plover.UserStreamAnalyzerService  - Exception while handling status update event: org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: not talking to master and retries used up; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoException: not talking to master and retries used up
```

...
    Caused by: org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: not talking to master and retries used up; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoException: not talking to master and retries used up

The stacktrace is here:

```
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoException: not talking to master and retries used up
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.innerCall(DBTCPConnector.java:314)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.innerCall(DBTCPConnector.java:316)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:257)
at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:310)
at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:295)
at com.mongodb.DBCursor._check(DBCursor.java:368)
at com.mongodb.DBCursor._hasNext(DBCursor.java:459)
at com.mongodb.DBCursor._fill(DBCursor.java:518)
at com.mongodb.DBCursor.toArray(DBCursor.java:553)
at com.mongodb.DBCursor.toArray(DBCursor.java:542)
at org.grails.datastore.mapping.mongo.query.MongoQuery$MongoResultList.<init>(MongoQuery.java:908)
at org.grails.datastore.mapping.mongo.query.MongoQuery$36.doInDB(MongoQuery.java:536)
at org.grails.datastore.mapping.mongo.query.MongoQuery$36.doInDB(MongoQuery.java:508)
```

I have setup a local test environment to replicate this problem. Here is the config output:

```
{
"set" : "rsMesh",
"date" : ISODate("2013-09-10T01:08:20Z"),
"myState" : 2,
"syncingTo" : "macbookpro.local:27018",
"members" : [
    {
        "_id" : 1,
        "name" : "macbookpro.local:27018",
        "health" : 1,
        "state" : 1,
        "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
        "uptime" : 9940,
        "optime" : {
            "t" : 1378767619,
            "i" : 5
        },
        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2013-09-09T23:00:19Z"),
        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2013-09-10T01:08:19Z"),
        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
        "pingMs" : 0
    },
    {
        "_id" : 2,
        "name" : "macbookpro.local:27019",
        "health" : 1,
        "state" : 7,
        "stateStr" : "ARBITER",
        "uptime" : 9914,
        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2013-09-10T01:08:19Z"),
        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
        "pingMs" : 0
    },
    {
        "_id" : 3,
        "name" : "macbookpro.local:27017",
        "health" : 1,
        "state" : 2,
        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
        "uptime" : 10392,
        "optime" : {
            "t" : 1378767619,
            "i" : 5
        },
        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2013-09-09T23:00:19Z"),
        "self" : true
    }
],
"ok" : 1
```

}

Replica set configuration has been set in Datasource.groovy as per documentation:

```
grails {
mongo {
    replicaSet = ["macbookpro.local:27017", "macbookpro.local:27018", "macbookpro.local:27019"]
}
```

}

So I am not running in standalone, the replica set servers are synched properly, and all servers are running properly. But if I force a new server to become the primary then all access appears to fail as if the driver was not redirecting queries to the new primary.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one ever answered this so I decided that the recovery from replica sets was non-functional. Instead I went to sharding and hoped that layering a mongos between the app server and the clusters themselves would provide enough protection.

The answer was a definitive "sort of". Before, when I stepped a primary down (or simulated a crash) the app server would hang indefinitely. Now I just get a few errors about not finding a primary in a given cluster and then the system recovers. Not a desirable solution but at least it is better than a permanent failure.